# Is a LASSO an acceptable way to deal with proportional data that sums to 1?

Tags: regression, lasso, proportion

I'm doing a study with five proportion predictors that sum to 1. I'm wondering if a LASSO regression is an appropriate analysis?

Comment: (Not the same Dave) What is your goal of doing the analysis? What problems do you encounter when you use a non-penalized estimation method, and what do you hope to gain by using LASSO?

Comment: I suppose you will only need, and can only use, 4 of the 5, since the 5th value will always be determined by the others.  The question then becomes whether LASSO will effectively choose the best 4, creating a new sort of "leave one out" strategy.  But since the 5 will be intertwined, such methods will hardly be helpful for a causal analysis.  Are you seeking a straight predictive model?  And even then, wouldn't it be more efficient simply to try each of those 5 possibilities, or perhaps a few more, rather than utilizing LASSO, which pays off when there are much larger sets of predictors?

Comment: I wonder if it would make sense to omit the intercept in this case. Then your mode matrix would have full rank, right?